# Fingeprint thinning code preserving continuity of ridges

Tags: opencv, fingerprint

I am trying to develop a project that involves fingerprint matching. Now, I am stuck at the stage of Fingerprint thinning. I am coding my project using OpenCV and c++ Visual Studio 2010.

I tried erode() function, but it doesn't preserve the continuity of ridge lines. I also tried the following algorithm of Zhang-Suen thinning,

http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-thinning-algorithm-in-opencv/

but, this shows an exception at memory location. I don't know how to proceed and i am stuck with this step.

Kindly help me with the code for fingerprint thinning + also preserving continuity of ridges.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a code example of extraction, SourceAFIS (BSD License) goes from full greyscale to binarized and thinned with some artifact trimming as well and then identifies minutia. It's written in c# but it might give you some bright ideas.